# JAX-RS : Client side: Intercepting redirection before the redirections are followed

Tags: redirect, jersey, jax-rs

I am trying to implement "redirect handler/filter" on JAX-RS(Jersey) client side. The expectation is that this handler would get invoked before actual redirection by Jersey takes place.

So far I could find is to disable follow redirect and implement own redirect  filter, but this means I have to implement full redirect handling including handling loops or other edge cases, which I am trying to avoid and want to rely on Jersey implementation.

I only want to add/change header or other parameters inside the request before actual redirection takes place. Also there are only few redirect we want to manipulate while let other redirections work as is.

Disabling redirect:

```
ClientBuilder
                .newBuilder()
                .withConfig(new ClientConfig(clientConfig))
                .property(ClientProperties.FOLLOW_REDIRECTS, false)
                .build();
```

Sample redirect handler:

```
        Response resp = requestContext.getClient().target(responseContext.getLocation()).request()
                .method(requestContext.getMethod());
        responseContext.setEntityStream((InputStream) resp.getEntity());
        responseContext.setStatusInfo(resp.getStatusInfo());
        responseContext.setStatus(resp.getStatus());
```

Are there any pointers or reference I can use to intercept redirect?

Comment: Unfortunately, redirection occurs at a lower level than Jersey. There are Connectors at the lower level, and these connectors handle the redirection. The default Connector uses the HttpUrlConnection. The property you set with Jersey to not follow redirects is simply forwarded to the HttpUrlConnection (which is configurable to follow or not follow redirects), which handles the redirection.